# ¿Como mostrar elementos distintos consecutivos en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Necesito enumerar elementos consecutivos en una bd con datos históricos , es decir, tiene una estampa de tiempo, por ejemplo cada 1 minuto, y un estado, entonces cuando ese estado cambia almaceno el dato, pero luego minuto a minuto tomo una muestra por lo tanto tango elementos repetidos hasta que cambia de estado, por ejemplo:

| Tiempo | Estado | Equipo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO1 |
| 1 | CERRADO | EQUIPO1 |
| 2 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO1 |
| 3 | CERRADO | EQUIPO1 |
| 4 | CERRADO | EQUIPO1 |
| 5 | CERRADO | EQUIPO1 |
| 6 | CERRADO | EQUIPO1 |
| 7 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO1 |
| 8 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO1 |
| 9 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO2 |
| 10 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO2 |
| 11 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO2 |
| 12 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO2 |
| 13 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO2 |
| 14 | CERRADO | EQUIPO2 |
| 15 | CERRADO | EQUIPO2 |

Si uso row_number para el campo estado me mostrara:

| Tiempo | Estado | Equipo | row number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO1 | 1 |
| 1 | CERRADO | EQUIPO1 | 1 |
| 2 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO1 | 2 |
| 3 | CERRADO | EQUIPO1 | 2 |
| 4 | CERRADO | EQUIPO1 | 3 |
| 5 | CERRADO | EQUIPO1 | 4 |
| 6 | CERRADO | EQUIPO1 | 5 |
| 7 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO1 | 3 |
| 8 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO1 | 4 |
| 9 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO2 | 5 |
| 10 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO2 | 6 |
| 11 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO2 | 7 |
| 12 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO2 | 8 |
| 13 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO2 | 9 |
| 14 | CERRADO | EQUIPO2 | 6 |
| 15 | CERRADO | EQUIPO2 | 7 |

Y yo lo que necesito es numerar los repetidos consecutivos por equipo y mostrar algo como:

| Tiempo | Estado | Equipo | row number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO1 | 1 |
| 1 | CERRADO | EQUIPO1 | 1 |
| 2 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO1 | 1 |
| 3 | CERRADO | EQUIPO1 | 1 |
| 4 | CERRADO | EQUIPO1 | 2 |
| 5 | CERRADO | EQUIPO1 | 3 |
| 6 | CERRADO | EQUIPO1 | 4 |
| 7 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO1 | 1 |
| 8 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO1 | 2 |
| 9 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO2 | 1 |
| 10 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO2 | 2 |
| 11 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO2 | 3 |
| 12 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO2 | 4 |
| 13 | ABIERTO | EQUIPO2 | 5 |
| 14 | CERRADO | EQUIPO2 | 1 |
| 15 | CERRADO | EQUIPO2 | 2 |

He intentado diferentes cosas pero no logro dar con la solución, espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: No se entiende cual es la lógica para numerar, podrías explicar a detalle por qué las primeras 4 filas tienen el mismo número y luego va consecutivo en las siguientes 3, luego regresa a uno?

Comment: Si, me explico, necesito contar cada estado nuevo, en la tabla el primero es ABIERTO EQUIPO1 (1) luego CERRADO EQUIPO1(vuelve a ser uno porque es un estado nuevo) luego ABIERTO EQUIPO1(vuelve a ser 1 porque a pesar que abierto equipo1 ya existe entre medio hay un cerrado por lo que es un estado nuevo) luego nuevamente es CERRADO EQUIPO1(mismo caso anterior, ya existe este estado pero paso por abierto por lo que es un estado nuevo) luego viene CERRADO EQUIPO1 (aquí ya no es nuevo ya que el estado anterior para este equipo es cerrado, por eso el contador sube a 2)

Comment: entonces cuando para el mismo equipo encuentra un estado nuevo el contador vuelve a 1. No se si me explique mejor

Answer (score 1):

Este es un tema con distintas complicaciones que en inglés llaman 'Gaps and Islands' (brechas e islas). Una de las forma más sencillas y eficientes es la que dejo a continuación. Es la combinación entre un row_number sin particiones, con uno con particiones que nos permite agrupar distintos datos en "islas". Así, ya solo tenemos que hacer un nuevo row_number usando esa nueva columna para particionarlo.

```
--Creamos los datos de prueba
CREATE TABLE #Prueba(
    Tiempo  int,
    Estado  varchar(20),
    Equipo  varchar(20),
    res     int
);
INSERT INTO #Prueba
VALUES
        (0  , 'ABIERTO', 'EQUIPO1', 1),
        (1  , 'CERRADO', 'EQUIPO1', 1),
        (2  , 'ABIERTO', 'EQUIPO1', 1),
        (3  , 'CERRADO', 'EQUIPO1', 1),
        (4  , 'CERRADO', 'EQUIPO1', 2),
        (5  , 'CERRADO', 'EQUIPO1', 3),
        (6  , 'CERRADO', 'EQUIPO1', 4),
        (7  , 'ABIERTO', 'EQUIPO1', 1),
        (8  , 'ABIERTO', 'EQUIPO1', 2),
        (9  , 'ABIERTO', 'EQUIPO2', 1),
        (10 , 'ABIERTO', 'EQUIPO2', 2),
        (11 , 'ABIERTO', 'EQUIPO2', 3),
        (12 , 'ABIERTO', 'EQUIPO2', 4),
        (13 , 'ABIERTO', 'EQUIPO2', 5),
        (14 , 'CERRADO', 'EQUIPO2', 1),
        (15 , 'CERRADO', 'EQUIPO2', 2);

--Aquí inicia la solución
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY Tiempo) 
            - ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY EQUIPO, Estado ORDER BY Tiempo) grupos
    FROM #Prueba  --Cambia por el nombre de tu tabla
)
SELECT Tiempo,
        Estado,
        Equipo,
        res, --esta es solo para comparar los resultados esperados.
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY Grupos, Estado, Equipo ORDER BY Tiempo)
FROM CTE
ORDER BY Tiempo;
```